# TCDPF render a pdf with a png image, problem with transparent png

Tags: tcpdf

If i render a pdf with a png file, i get the following error.

What's the problem with this?

```
Warning

Message: imagepng(/...examplepathfolder.../tmp/__tcpdf_172a5566d5e348eba254a398c0909340_imgmask_alpha_2e51083373b9767f3e6183dfb1d0d48e): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: tcpdf/tcpdf.php
```

it seems that is a problem with a transparent png file if i try the same with a jpeg there is no error.

There is an example to work with transparent files, https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_042/

For me i wont't understand what i have to change with my code

```
$info_left_column .= pdf_logo_url();
$pdf->MultiCell(($dimensions['wk'] / 2) - $dimensions['lm'], 0, $info_left_column, 0, 'J', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, true, true, 0);
```

pdf_logo_url() returns the absolute path of the png file.

Comment: Can you share your code using a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: problem is solved, a wrong temp-folder was in config file..thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

omg i found the problem.

So, under normal use the temp-folder ("K_PATH_CACHE") is not in use for tcpdf. If you use a png the temp-folder is important to create a second image to prepare problems with the alpha-channel.
So, in my installation was a wrong temp-folder, so i changed it and now all works fine :-)

Answer (score 1):

As I showed in the picture, just uncomment this line:

```
 //define ('K_PATH_CACHE', '/tmp/');
```

[image: ...]

Comment: Please read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](How do I write a good answer?). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.